# Why no result from os.popen() when script is run from crontab?

Tags: python-3, cron

When I run this Python3 script from the command line or from Thonny I get correct results. When I run it through crontab the variables ipaddress an ssid stay empty.

Can anyone tell me why? Any suggestions to solve it?

```
import dweepy, os

ipaddress = os.popen("ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet' | awk '/inet / {print $2}'").read()
ssid = os.popen("iwconfig wlan0 | grep 'ESSID' | awk '{print $4}' | awk -F\\\" '{print $2}'").read()

data = ssid[:-1] + ' ' + ipaddress[:-1]

dweepy.dweet_for('NorthWestern', {'here I am':data})
```

This script should let me know the ip address and the SSID of the wifi to which my headless Pi is connected.

Edit: this is the line in crontab:

```
* * * * * python3 /home/pi/PythonON5MF/send_ip_v001.py &
```

Comment: Please can you provide the full contents of your crontab.

Comment: Do you start it from cron at reboot? Most likely, it is run before the WLAN is connected. Try to start the same script at a later time.

Comment: no I don't start it at reboot, I let it run every minute for testing. When I have this working I'll modify the script to only send me a dweet if SSID/IP change

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your actual question is. Don't you know the SSID - if so how does the Pi connect? Is there any reason to use that convoluted popen when you could just use `hostname -I` to get the IP address? The "&" in cron seems superfluous  for a script that runs once.

Comment: The question is why the os.popen() does not give a result when the script is run in crontab. I want the Pi to let me know to which SSID it is connected and what is its IP address. I have a few different wifi routers and when I move around I want to know to which router it is connected.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution... add sudo inside de os.popen() command:

```
ipaddress = os.popen("sudo ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet' | awk '/inet / {print $2}'").read()
```